# QueryOver fails with could not resolve property:

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I am using NHibernate 3.0 and was comparing Query and QueryOver

```
var p = _prepo.Query<Party>()
            .Where(c => c.Person.LastName == "Bobby")
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above works, I get proxy class for p.Person if I view the object graph.

```
var p = _prepo.QueryOver<Party>()
            .Where(c => c.Person.LastName == "Bobby")
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This one fails with error ==> could not resolve property: Person.LastName of:

Why?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the NHibernate.Linq extension. I discovered that the resulting SQL questions is almost exactly the same (at least for this type of question (I would call it a "first order nested query")).

`Note:` If the `LastName` had been the primary/foreign key the `QueryOver` would have worked just as it was written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Linq provider but when using `QueryOver` you have to use a join to do a query like that:

#### Example 1

```
IQueryOver<Cat,Kitten> catQuery =
session.QueryOver<Cat>()
    .JoinQueryOver(c => c.Kittens)
        .Where(k => k.Name == "Tiddles");
```

#### Example 2

```
Cat catAlias = null;
Kitten kittenAlias = null;

IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
        .JoinAlias(() => catAlias.Kittens, () => kittenAlias)
        .Where(() => catAlias.Age > 5)
        .And(() => kittenAlias.Name == "Tiddles");
```

Comment: I wish QueryOver was straight forward like Query, but good to know the workaorund.

Comment: `IQueryOver` method doesn't work. NHibernate keeps giving me a "Couldn't resolve property `Kitten` of `Cat`"

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use Linq in this case because the filtering is being done on the client, not in the database. So it is actually the `IEnumerable` version of Where that is running which is not related to NHibernate.

The QueryOver uses `Expression<Func<T,object>>` which NHibernate tries to translate to SQL but fails. For reasons unknown to me you must explicitly join using JoinQueryOver or JoinAlias.

Some more info on QueryOver here:
http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html